Extract zip file with vba
I'm trying to extract files from a folder with the zip extension in vba, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Please help.
Sub ExtractAllFiles()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ShellStr
    FileName = Dir("C:\Documents and Settings\ello\Desktop\*.zip")
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        ShellStr = "C:Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe " & FileName & " C:\Documents and Settings\ello\Desktop"
        Call Shell(ShellStr, vbHide)
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub


Also, keep in mind that the Dir function returns ONLY the filename/extension and does not include the full path.

shouldn't there be a backslash before Program Files? "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe "
